# Serializing a class with dynamic attribute to and from JSON

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization, dynamic

I have a class with 2 fields as ENUM and 3rd field as dynamic. The third field may contain Enum, Object, list or a string.

This dynamic field is throwing error when json.encode is executed.

This is my class:

```
    class Msg {
  /// Constructor
  Msg({
    required this.type,
    required this.signal,
    **required this.content,**
  });

  /// Create the model from Json.
  Msg.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    type = Type.values[json['Type'] as int];
    signal = Signal.values[json['Signal'] as int];
    **content = json['SyncContent'] as dynamic;**
  }

  Type? type;

  Signal? signal;

  /// Actual message it may be string or object or objectList
  **dynamic syncContent;**

  /// Create a Json object of the message.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final data = <String, dynamic>{};

    data['Type'] = type!.name;
    data['Signal'] = signal!.name;
    **data['Content'] = content!;**

    return data;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{"Type": ${type!.index} , "Signal": ${signal!.index}, "content": $content}';
  }
}
```

Msg.toString() returns the following JSON string

```
JSON {"Type": 0 , "Signal": 3, "Content": content.start }
```

when I call

```
json.decode(messageJson) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

It throws error for converting Content back to dynamic. Following is the error:

```
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 50)
{"Type": 0 , "Signal": 3, "Content": Content.start}
                                     ^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1405:5)
Reload already in progress, ignoring request
```

Is there any way to convert a class containing dynamic field to JSON and back from JSON to class.

Answer (score 0):

json in dart only accept `String`, `boolean`, `num` means `int` or `double`, `List`, `Map` and `null`. in you json `content.start` is not one of them. you cant decode it.

Comment: In my case other than `content.start` there may have Object, List, Map or String. To achieve this what can I do to pass various type of data on the place of `content.start`.

Comment: You should specify that and then add a method to decode it to dart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is` operator for easy handling in your `fromJson`

```dart
if (json['content'] is String)
content = json['content'] as String;
else if (json['content'] is List<String>)
content = json['content'] as List<String>;
```

and if your `content` contains another dart Model class then you have to use your `Model.fromJson` constructor